# Dow's Process for the manufacture of phenol

Tags: organic-chemistry

When chlorobenzene ($\ce{C6H5Cl}$) reacts with aqueous ($\ce{NaOH}$) solution it first forms sodium phenoxide ($\ce{C6H5ONa}$), and then phenol upon reacting with $\ce{H+}$.

But my question is, why can't $\ce{Na}$ directly replace $\ce{Cl}$ from chlorobenzene by breaking $\ce{Na-O}$ bond instead of breaking $\ce{O-H}$ bond?

Comment: You mean the Na from the NaOH?

Comment: Can you clarify what you think the mechanism is for this reaction? I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @Simon-Nail-It Yes sir, Na from NaOH

Comment: So your question is why can't $Na^{+}$ react directly with chlorobenzene instead of reacting with phenol?

Comment: @RokNarobe No sir, i mean to say that why is the long process used when we can just break the C-Cl bond in benzene and then Na+ can react with Cl to form NaCl and phenyl cation can react with OH- to give phenol. Why is Sodium Phenoxide is being formed before giving phenol ?

Comment: please  provide a clear idea about the mechanism of reaction in your mind.

Answer (score 4):

The mechanism of this reaction is that $\ce{NaOH}$ being a strong base with some extreme conditions abstracts  H from C adjacent to C containing Cl while Cl also leaves.

This creates benzyne as an intermediate.

Subsequent addition of $\ce{NaOH}$ forms the phenoxide ion.